# "I like to do cycling" or "I like to go for cycling" - which is correct?

Tags: prepositions, gerunds, objects

Which out of the two is correct?

> 1. I like to do cycling .
> 2. I like to go for cycling .

Is 'Cycling' in both the examples used in noun form?

Comment: What do you think yourself in particular. You can improve the question by specifying your problem with the sentences.

Comment: In the case of 2, I think most people would use "I like to go cycling".

Comment: You could even say, "I like to cycle."

Comment: **go for cycling** is not idiomatic. You like to "**go for** rides on your bike|bicycle"

Answer (score 4):

Neither would be commonly used in most dialects of English.  It would be more common to say "I like cycling" or "I like to go cycling".  Where I live (Canada) it would be even more common to say "I like to ride my bike/bicycle".

Comment: +1, but doesn't it largely depend on how seriously you are in to cycling. If you are a ten-year-old child, then "I like to ride my bicycle" seems apt. However if you are in training for the Tour de France, then something like "Cycling is my sport" is perhaps what you might say.

Comment: @WS2 I agree.  "Cycling" may or may not imply seriousness, but "riding a bike" implies a lack of seriousness.  I find in daily life that cyclists tend to refer to their specialization in cycling rather than "cycling" in general, however; e.g. "I like bicycle racing" or "I like mountain biking", although this isn't universal.